# Is there a universal application ID for sending MMS in J2ME?

Tags: java-me, mms, wma

I'm having problems with this.

The thing is that when I send an MMS with J2ME to another devices with JSR 205 (two tested: SonyEriccson w610i and Nokia 5300), a receiving icon flashes, but the message is not in the inbox folder. I think this happens because of the application ID -which may not be recognized-, so, is there a universal application ID -or another way- for sending MMSs in J2ME? Because I don't want to install a viewer (to receive the messages) on every single device.

The code I use is the same you can find all over the web: Open MessageConnection, create MultipartMessage, set address (mms://{number}:{appID}), add MessagePart and kick it out.

By the way, when I send it to a device without JSR 205 (an old SonyEriccson), it is received; But then again, not all the devices people will be sending MMSs may be that old.

And finally, the carrier is Telcel (Mexico). I don't know if this has something to do with it, but maybe.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I do alot of j2me dev, and it's a painful experience working with some of the APIs - like MMS. I've never worked with MMS so can't help you out, but wanted to wish you good luck :) I empathize with your pains

Comment: as ockberto said, you have to use the appID only if you need to receive the message in other MIDlet, so since you need to receive it in the inbox you have to remove the appID.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This makes the magic:

```
//String address = "mms://"+ number +":"+ appID;
String address = "mms://"+ number;
```

Every mobile is receiving the message now. But I don't know if it's correct sending messages like this, maybe future versions could complain.